# How to store and retrieve latest utf8mb4 emoji / smiley characters in lucene index

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, emoji, emoticons

Using a lucene index, is there any way to store and retrieve utf8 and utf8mb4 emoji / smiley characters? In any recent lucene version?

I don't want to search on it.

**UPDATE1:**

for the given data like this...

> bcdeewillifindfgh​

when i tried to retrieve from lucene index

[image]

Comment: Have you tried storing emojis in ES? That definitely works out of the box, give it a shot!

Comment: IMO, If elasticsearch supports storing emoji, lucene should support the same rit? am i missing any?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to...  Are you having some particular problem with it?

Comment: @femtoRgon Please check my update in post.. am i missing anything?

Comment: Your sample data works fine for me.  Looks like the data is not being correctly encoded somewhere along the line.

Comment: @femtoRgon So do we need to specifically encode smiley characters someway before putting in index? any code snippet will be much helpful.. thanks

Comment: It's hard to say where the problem is without seeing code.  It looks like it's getting ASCII encoded somewhere.  Maybe a file or database read issue or something.  For a simple example, this creates the string you are seeing:  `byte[] bytes = "bcdeewillifindfgh​".getBytes();  String result = new String(bytes, "ASCII");`

Comment: @femtoRgon your are right. i used blob column in mysql database. And also i missed to read that blob column properly.. Thanks a lot